# Oracle match a pattern where the suffix is only numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to SELECT from a table so that I can specify the prefix and constrain the "%" to only numbers

So like if I have

```
column
------
abc123
abc124
abc0023
abcdef
```

If I do like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column LIKE 'abc%'` then it finds all of them.

I want to only the ones with the numeric suffix. And in fact I really want the MAX() of that if it matters.

The prefix may be any length string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the comment you left in Gordon't answer, it appears that you want to do something like this:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2  (select 'abc123' from dual union
  3   select 'ABc124' from dual union
  4   select 'ABC0023' from dual union
  5   select 'ABCdef' from dual
  6  )
  7  select col
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_like(col, 'abc\d+$', 'i');

COL
-------
ABC0023
ABc124
abc123
```

What does it do?

- `abc` represents a string you're looking for
- `\d+` represents any number
- `$` means that the number must be placed at the end of the COL
- `i` means that search will be case-insensitive

Answer (score 4):

You can use `regexp_like()`:

```
where regexp_like(column, '[0-9]+$')
```

This simply says that the column ends in one or more digits.

Comment: so like where regexp_like(column, 'abc[0-9]+$') ? Doesn't seem to work. It just returns null. Also, how can run "UPPER" against the base part of the string and the columns to make sure the cases are all the same?